# Relation between NEF and synchronous explanation of cognition

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, nef, synchronization

I'm having a hard time determining if synchrony (I'm talking about the type described in reference to the visual cortex as seen [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19668703) and less about synaptic plasticity which also involves synchrony) based explanations are opposed or integrate-able with the NEF.

I seem to be only able to find evidence that the NEF is opposed to this type of explanation. The visual system of the [Spaun](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/338/6111/1202) (which is kind of the flagship model for the NEF) doesn't seem to use or exhibit synchrony. Additionally, [Eric Crawford's research on knowledge representation](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/publications/crawford2013.html) also seems to only criticize the synchronous approach.

However, it does seem that synchrony has a lot of empirical evidence, according to "[Neural Synchrony in Cortical Networks](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19668703)".

Can the NEF and synchrony work together somehow?

Comment: What is NEF...?

Comment: @draks Its defined in the tag so I didn't bother defining it in the question.